# Use imaginary number in C++ Armadillo?

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am using C++ with Armadillo to use an imaginary number.

Previously I used MATLAB, but it seems to work differently in Armadillo.

MATLAB code snippet is

```
position = 500 * sqrt(3)/2 + 0.5i;
```

How should I use this code in C++ Armadillo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::complex<double> position(500 * std::sqrt(3)/2 , 0.5);
```

Or

```
std::complex<double> ii(0,1);
std::complex<double> position = 500 * std::sqrt(3)/2 + 0.5*ii;
```

This all has nothing to do with the linear algebra library. Reading its documentation you can find that it also just uses the standard library complex type.